# Why do governments prescribe maximum ground coverage restrictions / building coverage ratio?

Tags: civil-engineering

I am an social science grad student who is writing a paper on the economic analyis of building regulations. While I could find quite a bit of literature on setbacks and floor area ratio , I couldn't find any literature on BCR . The only information I could get was from my urban planning professor that it reduced the impervious cover. But wouldn't that be ensured by setbacks with open spaces in it ? Any help in this regard will be very much appreciated

Comment: No knowledge on the subject but setbacks are much more limiting I assume. Setbacks also impact the usability of a narrow of smaller plots more than larger ones.

Comment: Setbacks can be hardscaped. They are more about visual impacts. You want a storm water runoff management system; and a minimum percentage of non-impervious area is a normal part of the plan.

Comment: See "Stormwater Calculations" https://www.hendersoncountync.gov/sites/default/files/fileattachments/site_development_water_resources/page/119411/plan_checklist_for_designers_01_10_2011.pdf

Comment: BTW, as a social science guy, you can appreciate that the economic impact of regulations is basically the cost of hiring the expediter that will get you out of having to worry about them.

Comment: @DKNguyen I suspect it depends upon how setbacks are specified. For example, some states in India specify increases in setback with increase in plot area

Comment: @PhilSweet Thank you for the link. But couldn't the same purpose be served by setbacks mandated to be left open to air? Some states in India do that

Comment: @PhilSweet haha. To be more serious I am looking at compliance costs for the regulation.

Comment: If you use setbacks to achieve BCR, your setbacks have to be more restrictive. If what you actually want to control is BCR, using an explicit BCR regulation allows more flexible setback regulation.

Answer (score 0):

In city planning one of the tools for regulating zoning density and complying with natural lighting and ventilation of the structures is controlling the Ground Coverage Ratio, massing and volume, and height of the buildings.

Ideally, there is an optimal density that works well with the environmental impact of a project. Such as the availability of enough public services, transportation, pollution control, educational facilities, health, and security. etc.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Are there any articles that estimates the impact of these controls on these variables ?

Comment: @RadDragon, I am guessing there are. I bet there are civil engineering specialties focused on this. I know many of the projects I did the structural design had a voluminous environmental impact prepared by a consultant.

Comment: Also to reduce fire spread risk. More likely to be mentioned in places where fire-spread-risk from adjacent buildings has been historically significant.

Comment: services, transport, education -- that's why there is FCR (floor coverage ratio) regulations where that is a primary concern.